# check if SVN repository has the location before checking in - python

Tags: python, svn

I create a new folder every time my job is run at different locations. I want to check if the folder exists in SVN before trying to checking it in. I've tried to do this by executing a check out command or svn ls command (which would fail if folder does't exists) and read the error and see if "not found" exists in the svn response.

I was hoping there should be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

There're two ways to do this.

1. I prefer to use [pysvn](http://pysvn.tigris.org).
2. Or you can try "svn status". The output is pretty formated like

   `?       newfolder`

   The "?" mark indicates a new fild/folder in svn.